# How to bulk/mass import/create webform components?

Tags: 7, entities, webforms, importing-exporting

Apart from his module : [webform_auto_field](http://drupal.org/project/webform_auto_field), is there any way to bulk import or create multiple components in a webform. Even if it is one type of component at a time.

I've already googled on, and didn't get sufficient response..

Thank you all in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [Webform Share](http://drupal.org/project/webform_share) module can solve your problem?

Comment: It was the missing piece in my castle bricks... thank you very much :)